# In Fragment using web service call, how to eliminate delay to display GridView list

Tags: android, fragment

I built a fragment which use data in a web service call to display gridView list. It has about .5 second of delay to actually grab data and display the gridView on xml. Issue is that Everytime I come back from other pages or reorient the view, the delay happens. I don't know what I am missing but should the system save the last view in memory to display before it gets the real data from web service whenever I come back from other pages?

```
public class fragment_grid_room extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = fragment_grid_room.class.getName();

    public fragment_grid_room() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //start async task to display rooms

        DisplayGridRooms gridRooms = new DisplayGridRooms();
        gridRooms.execute(new String[] { "params" });

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_roomgrid, container, false);

        //rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //add current date
        TextView dayTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.currentDate);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
        Date now = new Date();
        String strDate = sdf.format(now);
        Log.d(TAG, "*****strdate"+strDate);
        dayTV.setText(strDate);

        return rootView;

    }





    //async task to display rooms
    private class DisplayGridRooms extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {
        JSONArray jsonArrayRooms;

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... url) {
            String email = getResources().getString(R.string.temp_login);
            String pwd = getResources().getString(R.string.temp_pwd);
            String username = "apark@anexinet.com";
            webServiceRoom wsRoom = new webServiceRoom();
            jsonArrayRooms = wsRoom.getRoomList(email, pwd, username);
            //System.out.println("222******returning jsonroom with: "+jsonRoom.length());
            return jsonArrayRooms;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArrayRooms) {

            ArrayList<roomGrid> room_list = new ArrayList<roomGrid>();
            int totalNumRooms=jsonArrayRooms.length();
            int availNum=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayRooms.length(); i++) {
                roomGrid roomObject = new roomGrid();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonRoom = jsonArrayRooms.getJSONObject(i);
                    String[] temp = jsonRoom.getString("roomName").split("-");
                    String[] temp2 = temp[1].split("\\(");
                    roomObject.setRoomName(temp2[0].trim());
                    String roomStat = jsonRoom.getString("statusText");
                    roomObject.setStatus(roomStat);
                    room_list.add(roomObject);

                    if(roomStat.toLowerCase().contains("available")){ //count available rooms
                        availNum+=1;
                    };

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "json array exception for rooms:" + ex);
                }
            }

            final GridView gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridview_room);

            //set availability bar
            TextView avalBar = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.availableBar);
            String availbilityText = "Available "+availNum+" of "+totalNumRooms;
            avalBar.setText(availbilityText);

            Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
            View v = window.getDecorView();
            ImageButton imageGrid = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.gridButton);
            imageGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;
            int numColFinal = 1;
            if (width > 350) {
                double numCol = width / 350;
                numColFinal = (int) numCol;
            }
            gridView.setNumColumns(numColFinal);
            Log.d(TAG, "screen width, numColFinal=" + width + "," + numColFinal);


          //  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdaptorRoomGrid(getActivity(), room_list));

            //when list is clicked, move to detail page
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    Object o = gridView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    roomGrid fullObject = (roomGrid)o;
                    String roomName = fullObject.getRoomName();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RoomTimeslotActivity.class)
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, roomName);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            });

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix the issue is by storing data in shared preferences every time you close your fragment.

First a little improvement. You can move the code below from `onPostExecute()` in `doInBackground()`. And then rather return JSONArray in `onPostExecute()` you can return your list of `roomGrid`

```
List<roomGrid> room_list = new ArrayList<roomGrid>();
int totalNumRooms=jsonArrayRooms.length();
int availNum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayRooms.length(); i++) {
    roomGrid roomObject = new roomGrid();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonRoom = jsonArrayRooms.getJSONObject(i);
        String[] temp = jsonRoom.getString("roomName").split("-");
        String[] temp2 = temp[1].split("\\(");
        roomObject.setRoomName(temp2[0].trim());
        String roomStat = jsonRoom.getString("statusText");
        roomObject.setStatus(roomStat);
        room_list.add(roomObject);
        if(roomStat.toLowerCase().contains("available")){ 
            //count available rooms
            availNum+=1;
        };
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "json array exception for rooms:" + ex);
    }
}
```

In your class RoomGrid (the one you add in your list), add

- method `toJson()` - which creates a `JSONObject`instance representing your data
- static method `public static RoomGrid from(JSONObject json)` - which will create and return an `RoomGrid` instance (or null if json is null, empty, etc)

In you `CustomAdaptorRoomGrid` add
- `getItems()` which will return the list of `RoomGrid` you supplied when creating the adapter

in your fragment `onDestroyView()` add:

```
CustomAdaptorRoomGrid adapter = (CustomAdaptorRoomGrid) gridView.getAdapter();
int length = adapter != null && adapter.getItems() != null ? adapter.getItems().size() : 0;

if (length > 0) {
    // create a JSONArray from the list
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for (RoomGrid item : adapter.getItems()) {
        array.put(item.toJson();
    }

    // add the value in preferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = ...;
    prefs.edit().put("YOUR_KEY", array.toString()).apply();
}
```

And finally in your fragment `onViewCreated()` check for the array from the shared preferences and revert it to a list of your items and supply them to the adapter.

Then engage your task to download and refresh whatever you need.